# Before Uploaded File To Server Want To Allocation 10 MB

Tags: php

I have a host. Its max upload file limit is 10MB. When a user is selected a file and starting to upload file to server I want to allocation the file to 10mb if its bigger than 10 mb. Can I make that?

NOTE: I use PHP

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines at top of your script to allow 100 MB to upload.

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
```

You can change it via an `.htaccess` file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

Comment: When I click on upload button its start to upload, but in 10 or 15 seconds later the page is give a message "The page cannot be display"

Note: set_time_limit(0); its disabled.

Comment: its on this link pastebin.com/HGvWWxhQ

Comment: Try `.htaccess` solution from my answer.